# Selecting a surface format for the swapchain?

Tags: vulkan

The function `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR` returns a list of supported `VkSurfaceFormatKHRs` for a given physical device and surface:

```
struct VkSurfaceFormatKHR {
    VkFormat format;
    VkColorSpaceKHR colorSpace;
};
```

When creating a swapchain for a surface you must select the required `VkFormat` and `VkColorSpaceKHR` in `VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR`...

```
struct VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR {
    /* ... */
    VkFormat imageFormat;
    VkColorSpaceKHR imageColorSpace;
    /* ... */
};
```

and these must match one of the `VkSurfaceFormatKHRs`.

What is a example implementation of a function:

```
VkSurfaceFormatKHR SelectSurfaceFormat(std::vector<VkSurfaceFormatKHR>)
```

That selects a `VkSurfaceFormatKHR` from the multiple `VkSurfaceFormatKHRs` returned by `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR` in a way that is reasonably general-purpose?

Comment: There is no "typical algorithm". You have to exercise good judgment, informed by the needs of your application and the characteristics of the display device.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Question updated.

Comment: Now you've turned the question into a "find off-site resources" question. What do you hope to gain by seeing someone else's code for this?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Question updated.  I don't think the answer is as dependent on the "needs of the application" as you seem to suggest.  I think it is a reasonable question to ask what the typical or common selection algorithm is.

Comment: "*I don't think the answer is as dependent on the "needs of the application" as you seem to suggest.*" Sure it is; how wouldn't it be? Some applications may want to render directly to the swapchain image. So if they need, for example, destination alpha, then they need to pick a format that provides enough alpha bits. By contrast, I rather suspect that a 2D console emulator that's just using Vulkan to throw an image onto the screen cares about alpha bits at all.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Ok, assume the program is a fullscreen 3D program like a game or a CAD app, and the swapchain images are the final destination for the entire fullscreen window.

Answer (score 1):

You should exercise the same discretion when choosing a format that you would when choosing a physical device.

If you have a preference for color precision, like if you had a preference for physical device capabilities, I suggest building a list of your preferred formats and running a typical for loop to check if they are supported in order.

If you don't have a preference in any way, you might model your app after the [LunarG Vulkan Sample](https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanSamples/blob/master/API-Samples/05-init_swapchain/05-init_swapchain.cpp#L144) project which asserts that `size of surfaceFormats > 0` and defaults to surfaceFormats[0].

The sample also handles the case that `surfaceFormats[0] == VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED`, but as mentioned in the comments, this is no longer a valid value and may be omitted.

Comment: Any kind of ordering is not guaranteed by the specification. Conformant application should not rely on this just because "in many cases". Only perhaps as a last resort. If the user wants classic 24-32 format, he should test for it explicitly. Furthemore, `VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED` is not valid, so that would be a driver bug.

Comment: @krOoze, you're right that I should not have asserted that that method was valid "in most cases". I've updated my answer.

Comment: @krOoze As mentioned in the [LunarG Vulkan Sample](https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanSamples/blob/master/API-Samples/05-init_swapchain/05-init_swapchain.cpp#L144), it is asserted there that if the supported formats list is > 0 and supportedFormats[0] is `VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED`, then a there is no preference and any format may be selected.
Does that go contrary to the spec?

Comment: Yes: "The number of format pairs supported **must** be greater than or equal to `1`. `pSurfaceFormats` **must** not contain an entry whose value for format is `VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED`". Though the code is technically good according version <1.1.111. But such incompatible changes to spec are usually made only if pretty sure that all drivers already behaved that way or are easily updateable. It is not bad, but handling that `VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED` case should not be needed, and it should not happen in the wild, so not worth speaking about.

Comment: This answer is right, so I'm not going to post a separate one, but if you don't have any other criteria, {VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, VK_COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR} (or other 8:8:8:8 R/G/B/A orderings) is very widely available and a good default choice.

Comment: @JesseHall Historically it is BGRA on Windows. E.g. NV only exposes BGRA.

Comment: BTW these stats may be useful here: https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listsurfaceformats.php